# Change spinner options from spinner onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner, android-studio-3.0

I've got a spinner up the top, showing books of the bible.  When a book is selected, I find out how many chapters there and place it in to the `Chapters` variable.  Then I want to change the spinner named `bible_chapters` based on how many chapters there are.

```
public class Find extends Fragment {

    private Spinner bibleBooks;
    private Spinner bibleChapters;
    private Spinner bibleVerses;
    private boolean spinnerInitialized;

    public Find() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find, container, false);
        final DatabaseManager databaseAccess = DatabaseManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        final Context con = getContext();

        // Spinner Listener
        bibleBooks = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bible_books);
        bibleChapters = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bible_chapters);

        bibleBooks.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (!spinnerInitialized) {
                    spinnerInitialized = true;
                    return;
                }

                databaseAccess.open();
                String book = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int Chapters = databaseAccess.howManyChapters(book);
                databaseAccess.close();
                Log.d("Chapters",String.valueOf(Chapters));
                if(Chapters > 1) {

                    List<String> newChapters = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int x = 2; x <= Chapters; x++) {
                        newChapters.add("Chapter " + x);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, bibleBooks, newChapters);
                    bibleBooks.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                return;
            }
        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

The error lies on the `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, bibleBooks, newChapters);` line.  It's the context that is the problem.  I've tried:

`this`,

`rootView`,

`getContext()`,

`getActivity()`,

The error I keep getting is:
`error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(Context,Spinner,List<String>)`

None of them seem to be what its looking for.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you try like this :- priivate Activity activity;  & below setContentview - --> activity=this;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android I always pass the spinnerItem, for example `Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, newChapters);
```

instead of the *bibleBooks *, which is the spinner itself.

EDIT:
For Java: `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`

Comment: try `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`

Comment: Looks good! So the solution was: `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newChapters);` - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In code `new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, bibleBooks, newChapters),` the second parameter must be resource id. For example, `new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, R.layout.item_spinner, newChapters);`

And `R.layout.item_spinner`:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_spinner"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_spinner"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying is wrong.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, bibleBooks, newChapters);
```

you are  passing `spinner` object instead of `layout resource id` .
try below it work for you.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,newChapters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()` in `Constructor` of `ArrayAdapter`

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), bibleBooks, newChapters);
                    bibleBooks.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**Hope this will help**

Comment: Okay sorry i didn't read carefully. I think you second parameter is wrong, you should give resource id. like   `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`